# How un deploy BPEL process ODE

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, bpel, ode, undeploy

How can a BPEL process deployed on ODE engine be un deployed? If there is infinite loop in BPEL process, the process hangs the ODE engine. I tried removing manually from the  ODE processes directory, but the process does not release the wsdl port below. This means I have to shutdown Tomcat server and restart to continue deploying other BPEL processes.

```
http://localhost:8081/ode/processes/TestProcess.
```

Comment: Port in the sense of a wsdl port, i.e. a bound port type?